# Merge multiple text files on one column in bash

Tags: bash, file, text, merge

How do you merge multiple plain text files (>2) on the first column? For example, I have three files like the below:

```
cat file1.txt 
a 1
b 2
c 3
cat file2.txt 
a 2
b 3
c 4
cat file3.txt
a 3
b 4
c 5
```

I am trying to merge these files into one file like in the first column like this:

```
cat ideal.txt
a 1 2 3
b 2 3 4
c 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `join`?

> Join lines of two sorted files on a common field.
> More information: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/join

```
join file1.txt file2.txt > join1.txt
join join1.txt file3.txt > ideal.txt
cat ideal.txt
```

[image]

Here's a script, I named the file "jj" you might use in order to work with many a file. To run it type: `./jj file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# define temporary location, WIP/CACHE
tmp="/tmp/outjointmp"
# define target location
out="/tmp/outjoin"
# truncate both files, just in case there is any residue from anything
: > "$out"
: > "$tmp"

# first, copy the contents of the first file into the target file
cat "$1" > "$out"
# loop through all remaining arguments
while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; do
  join "$out" "$2" > "$tmp"
  shift
  # copy over the temp into destination file
  cat "$tmp" > "$out"
done

cat "$out"
```

result&output:

```
$ ./jj file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
a 1 2 3
b 2 3 4
c 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works well for a few files but I have many files that need merging. Is there an efficient loop that could merge several files together?

Comment: I posted an example loop script for you

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function using process substitution should do the trick in order to `join` more than two files:

```
#!/bin/bash

join_rec() {
    if (($# <= 2)); then
        join "$@"
    else
        join "$1" <(join_rec "${@:2}")
    fi
}

join_rec file*.txt > joined_file
```

assuming input files are sorted.